# Nextjs - Access global context values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I would like to see how I can create global contexts in NextJS and have global variables inside the app.

Currently I have `AppContext.js` as

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

const AppContext = createContext();

export default AppContext
```

`_app.js`

```
const [socketio, setSocketio] = useState(null);
const appContext = {
  socketio
};

return(
  <AppContext.Provider value={ appContext }>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </AppContext.Provider>
)
```

How can I access the appContext values from another component? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useContext(AppContext) to access the data from any component... Like:

```
const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
```

And access each value like

```
appContext.socketio
```